# capacitor-admob Android compilation error?

Tags: javascript, android, build.gradle

Trying to get the `capacitor-admob` plugin working in Android.

It's currently throwing the following when I try to compile & run:

```
error: package androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget does not exist
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
                                 ^
```

I've added the following dependency to my app-level `build.gradle` (and re-synced):

```
implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
```

But no dice, it's still saying the package does not exist.

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: Have you updated the layout file as well as the java file? If it still doesn't work, update the build.gradle file of the npm module itself - although Android studio should have prompted you to do this anyway

Comment: Hey @AlokKumar thanks for replying. I'm new to Android development, where would I find the layout file and the npm module's build.gradle?

Comment: Nvm I found the npm module's build.gradle and have updated it. This seems to have solved the issue, cheers! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it if you like :)

Comment: Awesome, have posted as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you updated the layout file as well as the java file? If it still doesn't work, update the build.gradle file of the npm module itself - although Android studio should have prompted you to do this anyway